# Specializing a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I just created a template class

```
template< typename T >
class LinkedList {
private:
    struct LinkedListElement {
        T *m_data;
        LinkedListElement *m_next;
    };
    LinkedListElement *head;
public:
    void insert(T *elem);
    void remove(T *elem);
    T *find(const char *name);
};
```

and I want to customize what `find` method does for a certain class.

So, when I do my template specialization do I have to re-write the hole template implementation code or just t *find(like when subclassing)?

This is the first time I create my own template;)

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's called a "class template", because it's a template, not a class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this case, you can specialize the member function only

```
template<> inline MyType *LinkedList<MyType>::find(const char *name) { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Comment: Would you explain Why this case only? What cases won't fit?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're saying, but he is saying that when you want to specialize a particular function of a class template, you can do so.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was asking ;)